# Highest combined passer rating

Tags: american-football

Following last night's game between the Giants and Saints, where Drew Brees had a passer rating of 140.5 and Eli Manning had 138.2, does anyone know if there has been an NFL game where the combined rating was higher?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is looking for a specific statistic, which is [off-topic](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/583/sports-statistics-and-topicality).